# requery V.S Custom update

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager that it data comes from a Cursor , now this Cursor holds about 5000 record 
, anyway i have a button in each page in the ViewPager if the user click this button , an update to boolean field in the database should occur . so the question which is better , do a `requery()` on the `Cursor` after each update , or instead of doing that , i came with this solution

i define a `Map<Integer,Boolean>` `Integer`:for record `_id` `Boolean`:for the value of the  record field that will be updated, this map  initially will  start empty  and if the user click that button it will get the field value from the cursor  and flip it and add that value with the record _id to the map , and i have a HandlerThread which i use to post Runnable to make the real update statement to the Table , and it make's the job . is my solution better than call `requery()` for each update ?